# C++ priority_queue size() issue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I tried to get the size of an empty priority_queue. Something strange happened. Could anybody explain why this happened? Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, less<int> > asc_queue;
    cout << asc_queue.size() << " " << asc_queue.size() - 1 << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: why asc_queue.size()-1 is not -1?

Comment: Because it is an unsigned value. There is no -1 for unsigned values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::priority_queue::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/size) returns the size of the container as a `std::size_t` (technically the `size_type` of the underlying container of the priority queue) which is essentially an `unsigned int` - therefore trying to minus 1 from an empty container size gives you the unsigned decimal representation of `0xffffffffffffffffL` which is why you get the large value you see.

Comment: It gives you the unsigned decimal representation of 0xffffffffffffffffL. No overflow here.